# How to bulk insert JSON array of objects in MySQL in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm basically trying to bulk insert or update (on duplicate key) a JSON array of objects in a MySQL table using NodeJS. Sometimes JSON objects in array contain different key-value pairs.

A possible solution could be to loop over the JSON array first and then search each object for every key hardcoded from another array (corresponding to columns in table) then push result values in new array of arrays. In case a key does not exist in JSON object then fill with a "NULL" value.

Many thanks for any advice in advance!

```
var keys = ['customerId','subscriptionId','billingMethod','skuId','creationTime','planName','isCommitmentPlan','startTime','endTime','numberOfSeats','licensedNumberOfSeats','maximumNumberOfSeats','isInTrial','trialEndTime','renewalType','purchaseOrderId','status''customerDomain','skuName','suspensionReasons','dealCode'];

var demo_api = [{
  "kind": "reseller#subscription",
  "customerId": "C0123456",
  "subscriptionId": "123",
  "billingMethod": "ONLINE",
  "skuId": "Google-Apps-Unlimited",
  "creationTime": "1331647980142",
  "plan": {
    "planName": "ANNUAL",
    "isCommitmentPlan": true,
    "commitmentInterval": {
      "startTime": "1331647980142",
      "endTime": "1363183980142"
    }
  },
  "seats": {
    "kind": "subscriptions#seats",
    "numberOfSeats": 10,
    "licensedNumberOfSeats": 10,
    "maximumNumberOfSeats": 500
  },
  "trialSettings": {
    "isInTrial": false
  },
  "renewalSettings": {
    "kind": "subscriptions#renewalSettings",
    "renewalType": "SWITCH_TO_PAY_AS_YOU_GO"
  },
  "purchaseOrderId": "my_example.com_annual_1",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "customerDomain": "my_example.com",
  "skuName": "G Suite Business"
},
{
  "kind": "reseller#subscription",
  "customerId": "D0123456",
  "subscriptionId": "456",
  "billingMethod": "ONLINE",
  "skuId": "Google-Apps-For-Business",
  "creationTime": "1331647980142",
  "plan": {
    "planName": "FLEXIBLE",
    "isCommitmentPlan": false
  },
  "seats": {
    "kind": "subscriptions#seats",
    "licensedNumberOfSeats": 0,
    "maximumNumberOfSeats": 10
  },
  "trialSettings": {
    "isInTrial": false
  },
  "purchaseOrderId": "my_example_flex_1",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "customerDomain": "my_example2.com",
  "skuName": "G Suite Business"
}];
```

Desired result:

```
var result = [
    ["C0123456", "123", "ONLINE", "Google-Apps-Unlimited", "1331647980142", "ANNUAL", true, "1331647980142", "1363183980142", 10, 10, 500, false, "NULL", "SWITCH_TO_PAY_AS_YOU_GO", "my_example.com_annual_1", "ACTIVE", "my_example.com", "G Suite Basic", "NULL", "NULL"],
    ["D0123456", "456", "ONLINE", "Google-Apps-For-Business", "1331647980142", "FLEXIBLE", false, "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 0, 0, false, "NULL", "NULL", "my_example_flex_1", "ACTIVE", "my_example2.com", "G Suite Business", "NULL", "NULL"]
];
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object" (or a "JSON array")](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
  var myArray = new Array();

data.forEach((player) => {
  console.log(player.id);
  console.log(player);
  var playerModel ={
    id : player.id,
    firstname : player.firstname,
    lastname : player.lastname,
    position : player.position,
    price : player.price,
    appearences : player.appearences,
    goals : player.goals,
    assists : player.assists,
    cleansheets : player.cleansheets,
    redcards : player.redcards,
    yellowcards : player.yellowcards,
    image : player.image,
    clubid : player.clubid,
  };
  console.log("model"+playerModel.position);
  myArray.push(playerModel);
});
```

Here you need to change the model player in my code by a model created by you , and replace like this, just follow your json endpoint :

```
 var Mymodel = {
    bind: player.bind,
    ............
    ....
    }
```

the last step is that myArray is your results array , you need to loop it to see results

```
  for(let item of myArray) {
    console.log(item);
 console.log(item.bind);
.......................
}
```

Comment: Hi Fares, Thanks for your response. The problem is that not all the objects contains the same properties. For those non existent properties, I'd like to assign a "null" value.

Comment: the condition is about testing if property exists or not